# Scala implicit usage choices

Tags: scala, implicit

I've been wondering whether *transparent* `implicit` conversions are really such a good idea and whether it might actually be better to use implicits more, um, *explicitly*. For example, suppose I have a method which accepts a `Date` as a parameter and I have an implicit conversion which turns a `String` into a `Date`:

```
implicit def str2date(s: String) : Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(s)

private def foo(d: Date)
```

Then obviously I can call this with a transparent `implicit` conversion:

```
foo("20090910")
```

Would it be better to make the fact that I am converting the string into a date more explicit?

```
class DateString(val s: String) { 
  def toDate : Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(s) 
}

implicit def str2datestr(s: String) : DateString = new DateString(s)
```

So then the usage looks more like:

```
foo("20090910".toDate)
```

The advantage of this is that it is clearer later on what is happening - I've been caught out a few times now by transparent `implicit` conversions I should know about (`Option` to `Iterable` anyone?) and this usage still allows us to take advantage of the power of `implicit`s.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe that the more "explicit" way of doing implicit conversions is much better in terms of readability than the fully transparent one, at least in this example.

In my opinion, using `implicit`s fully transparently from type `A` to type `B` is OK when you can *always* view an object of type `A` as being able to be used whenever and object of type `B` is needed. For example, the implicit conversion of a `String` to a `RandomAccessSeq[Char]` always makes sense - a `String` can always, conceptually, be viewed as a sequence of characters (in C, a string is *just* a sequence of characters, for example). A call to `x.foreach(println)` makes sense for *all* `String`s.

On the other hand, the more explicit conversions should be used when an object of type `A` can *sometimes* be used as an object of type `B`. In your example, a call to `foo("bar")` does not makes sense and throws an error. As Scala does not have checked exceptions, a call to `foo(s.toDate)` clearly signals that there might be an exception thrown (`s` might not be a valid date). Also, `foo("bar".toDate)` clearly looks wrong, while you need to consult documentation to see why `foo("bar")` might be wrong. An example of this in the Scala standard library is conversions from `String`s to `Int`s, via the `toInt` method of the `RichString` wrapper (`String`s can be seen as `Int`s, but not *all the time*).

Answer (score 13):

When you make an implicit conversion from X to Y (like the conversion from String to Date above), you're essentially saying that, had you had full control over writing X in the first place, you would have made X implement or be a subclass of Y.

If it makes sense for X to implement Y, then add the conversion. If it doesn't, then maybe it's not appropriate. For example, it makes sense for String to implement RandomAccessSeq[Char], but maybe it doesn't make sense for String to implement Date (though String implementing StringDate seems fine).

(I'm a little late, and Flaviu has an excellent answer, but I wanted to add a comment about how I think about implicits.)