# Why does Scala implicitly convert Char to Int?

Tags: scala, types

Looking at scala's `Predef` object, which is automatically imported, I found the [following gem](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Predef$object.html#char2int%28Char%29)

```
implicit def char2int(x : Char) : Int
```

This has caused some sleazy bugs to sneak into my code (used `_1` instead of `_2` in `Map[Char,Int]`). I really don't get it, why would I want to *implicitly* convert `Char` to `Int`. The whole idea of having the `Char` type (which is a mere number) is so that I won't use it as a number (or vice versa).

I use scala's type system in order not to have errors like that!

The only (bad) excuse I though about is to be compatible with Java's horrible behaviour.

**update:** The main reason given by the two answers given so far, is that the implicit conversion is done to support ordered actions upon the `Char` type. So that for instance `'c'+1` would generate `d`. If that's what you want you should do

```
class Char ...
    ...
    def +(x:Int) = (this.toInt+x).toChar
    def <(x:Char) = this.toInt < x.toInt
```

and you could add and compare characters to your liking. The fact that `Char` is the only 16-bits number only means we need a new `Word` (or `Short`) type.

Comment: I've been bitten by this too, so you're not alone in wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you think in terms of how a `Char` is represented, a `Char` is jusr an unsigned 16 bit field, with a range from (0 to 2^16 - 1). This can fit without an overflow in an `Int` (32 bit signed, with a range from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1).

Some of Scala's basic types are, in order of the length of their representation in bits:

- `Byte` (8)
- `Char` (16)
- `Int` (32)
- `Long` (64)

All are signed, except for `Char` and all are convertible to a type "below" it as they would never over/under-flow (except for `Byte` to `Char`, which doesn't exist). See all of those implicit conversions in the [Predef](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_6_final/src/library/scala/Predef.scala?view=markup#L298).

This is the reason I believe the implicit conversions exist - to allow expressions like the following to exist:

```
def foo(c: Char) { println(c) }
foo('a' + 2) // prints c
```

Another explanation is along the lines of the one you have given (a `Char` is just a number...). For me it does make sense - the set of all `Chars` is included in the set of all `Int`s, and therefore, [applying my own guidelines for using implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404889/scala-implicit-usage-choices/1405096#1405096), the conversion should really be implicit.

I do understand your annoyance as I like compilers to signal errors like the one you have just gave as an example. It would be nice if Scala had a way to turn implicit conversion off (or turn *specific* implicit conversions off, as turning them all off would probably wreck havoc!)

The only solution I see for your problem is using `Map[RichChar, Int]` or something similar -  `RichChar` is implicitly converted to an `Int`, as implicit conversions cannot be chained. **EDIT** found out that there actually is *no* implicit conversion from `RichChar` to `Char`.

```
def foo(x: Int) = x + 1

import scala.runtime.RichChar

val ch = 'a'
val rch = new RichChar('a')

foo(ch) // compiles fine
// foo(rch) // does not compile

def bar(ch: Char) = println(ch) 

// bar(rch) // oops... does not compile
implicit def rch2char(rch: RichChar): Char = rch.self.asInstanceOf[Char]

bar(rch) // yay!
```

**EDIT**: Actually, if you have a good look at the Scala API, [`Char`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Char.html) does have an overloaded `+` method which takes an `Int` argument. Same goes for [`Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Int.html). This could have to do with the fact that the underlying JVM does something similar.

Also note that the example I have gave you had nothing to do with allowing adding `Int`s to `Char`s! This is already allowed by the API. The more subtle point is that when you add an `Int` to a `Char`, you get an `Int`. The implicit conversion is there to allow using the result of this addition as a `Char`.

Also note the more theoretical answer I have given - `Char` is a subset of `Int` !

`-- Flaviu Cipcigan`

Answer (score 1):

#### It may not be perfect but consider the alternative...

It's just an implementation choice. At one point, many languages did distinguish greatly between `char` and `int`, but since they always had to have conversion functions it didn't actually block very much and it *did* just become a big pain.

No one really wants to go back to the days of `chr(n)` and `ord(c)` all over the place. Imagine what fun UTF-8 handling would be.

Once C came out with `char`s really being `int`s, it rocked, and we've stayed with that even in much more strongly typed languages.

Now, should you really want an encapsulated `Char` that doesn't automatically convert, nothing stops you from defining a new type, say `ElazarChar`, for your own code. I suspect that you will hate it.

Comment: I considered the alternative and proposed one in the updated question.

Comment: You have very good points, but remember that the actual question you asked was not *"is this a good idea"* or *"how about this alternative"*, but *"Why does Scala..."*. I always try to answer the exact question asked, though that does often get me in trouble. Someone once asked how to shallow copy an (immutable) list so I gave that exact answer and got blasted for telling him to copy a val. :-)

Comment: I guess it's a bad idea to ask you "do you have a watch?" if I want to know the time...