# Why do I get different results when using a List than using a Tuple?

Tags: scala

If I try:

```
val someInput = List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))

for {
  (k,v) <- someInput
} yield (k,v)


 res0: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,2), (b,2))
```

While if I did:

```
for {
  (k,v) <- someInput
} yield List(k,v)

res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(97, 2), List(98, 2))
```

I don't understand why am I getting 97 & 98 when using a List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler automatically converts the key, which is a `Char`, to an `Int` (since JVM chars represent Unicode codepoints), because the value is an `Int` and Lists are homogenous. 97 and 98 are just the decimal representations of `'a'` and `'b'` in Unicode (and ASCII).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481839/why-does-scala-implicitly-convert-char-to-int) for why `Char` is implicitly converted to `Int` (Note that `Int` is not converted to `Char` because it is 32 bits whereas `Char` is only 16, so it might be a lossy conversion).

You can also do

```
for {
  (k,v) <- someInput
} yield List((k,v))
```

so that you yield a singleton list of `(Char, Int)` and your types are preserved. The result would be `List(List((a, 2)), List((b, 2)))`

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2 uses [weak conformance](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-drop-weak-conformance-from-the-language/2819) relation when inferring the least upper bound of primitive number types such that

```
List('a', 2)
```

is typed to `List[Int]` instead of, perhaps expected, `List[AnyVal]`. The compiler inserts `toInt`

```
List('a'.toInt, 2)
```

as explained by [SLS 6.26.1 Value Conversions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#value-conversions)

> If  has a primitive number type which [weakly conforms](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#weak-conformance) to the
>   expected type, it is widened to the expected type using one of the
>   numeric conversion methods `toShort`, `toChar`, `toInt`, `toLong`, `toFloat`,
>   `toDouble` defined in the standard library.

Weak conformance seems to be a [dropped feature](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/weak-conformance.html) in Scala 3, for example,

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> val a = 'a'
     | val i = 2
val a: Char = a
val i: Int = 2

scala> List(a, i)
val res0: List[AnyVal] = List(a, 2)
```

where we see dotty deduced `List[AnyVal]`. If we try to force the type to `List[Int]` then warning is raised

```
scala> val l: List[Int] = List(a,i)
1 |val l: List[Int] = List(a,i)
  |                        ^
  |Use of implicit conversion method char2int in object Char should be enabled
  |by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.implicitConversions'
  |or by setting the compiler option -language:implicitConversions.
  |See the Scala docs for value scala.language.implicitConversions for a discussion
  |why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
val l: List[Int] = List(97, 2)
```