# Could/should an implicit conversion from T to Option[T] be added/created in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-option

Is this an opportunity to make things a bit more efficient (for the prorammer): I find it gets a bit tiresome having to wrap things in `Some`, e.g. `Some(5)`.  What about something like this:

```
implicit def T2OptionT( x : T) : Option[T] = if ( x == null ) None else Some(x)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You would lose some type safety and possibly cause confusion.
For example:

```
  val iThinkThisIsAList = 2 
  for (i <- iThinkThisIsAList) yield { i + 1 }
```

I (for whatever reason) thought I had a list, and it didn't get caught by the compiler when I iterated over it because it was auto-converted to an Option[Int].

I should add that I think this is a great implicit to have explicitly imported, just probably not a global default.

Comment: At least in IntelliJ IDEA I can see when something gets auto-converted (by default it is underlined).  But maybe there should be a way to specify that an implicit conversion should only happen when passing the value to a method, not when calling a method on it.

Answer (score 28):

Note that you could use the [explicit implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404889/scala-implicit-usage-choices/1405096#1405096) pattern which would avoid confusion and keep code terse at the same time.

What I mean by explicit implicit is rather than have a direct conversion from `T` to `Option[T]` you could have a conversion to a wrapper object which provides the means to do the conversion from `T` to `Option[T]`.

```
class Optionable[T <: AnyRef](value: T) {
  def toOption: Option[T] = if ( value == null ) None else Some(value)
}

implicit def anyRefToOptionable[T <: AnyRef](value: T) = new Optionable(value)
```

... I might find a better name for it than `Optionable`, but now you can write code like:

```
val x: String = "foo"
x.toOption // Some("foo")

val y: String = null
x.toOption // None
```

I believe that this way is fully transparent and aids in the understanding of the written code - eliminating all checks for null in a nice way.

Note the `T <: AnyRef` - you should only do this implicit conversion for types that allow `null` values, which by definition are reference types.

Comment: Hi Flaviu, interesting suggestion.  I like it overall - though I think it makes my problem worse not better, now instead of typing Some() I have to type toOption... but it does have the advantage of working with null.

Comment: @flaviu-cipcigan, does the same but shorter - 
implicit class IntWithTimes[T](x: T) {
  def toOption: Option[T] = if (x != null) Option(x) else None
}

Answer (score 13):

The general guidelines for implicit conversions are as follows:

- When you need to add members to a type (a la "open classes"; aka the "pimp my library" pattern), convert to a *new* type which extends `AnyRef` and which only defines the members you need.
- When you need to "correct" an inheritance hierarchy.  Thus, you have some type `A` which *should have* subclassed `B`, but didn't for some reason.  In that case, you can define an implicit conversion from `A` to `B`.

These are the *only* cases where it is appropriate to define an implicit conversion.  Any other conversion runs into type safety and correctness issues in a hurry.

It really doesn't make any sense for `T` to extend `Option[T]`, and obviously the purpose of the conversion is not simply the addition of members.  Thus, such a conversion would be inadvisable.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that this could be confusing to other developers, as they read your code.

Generally, it seems, `implicit` works to help cast from one object to another, to cut out confusing casting code that can clutter code, but, if I have some variable and it somehow becomes a `Some` then that would seem to be bothersome.

You may want to put some code showing it being used, to see how confusing it would be.

Comment: I get your drift.. However, the point of Option[T] is that it can hold a value or a None, so it seems intuitive to me that if a method takes a variable of type Option[T] I should be able to pass a T into it.  Can you think of an example where you might have some confusion, e.g. a variable becoming a Some inadvertently?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to overload the method :

```
def having(key:String) = having(key, None)

def having(key:String, default:String) = having(key, Some(default))

def having(key: String, default: Option[String]=Option.empty) : Create = {
  keys += ( (key, default) )
  this
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That looks good to me, except it may not work for a primitive T (which can't be null).  I guess a non-specialized generic always gets boxed primitives, so probably it's fine.