# Scala - implicit conversion from T to Some[T]

Tags: scala

Consider this piece of code

```
def foo(b: Int) = ???

val a = 3
foo(a)
```

It works fine of course, but let's say that later I decided that `foo` should support an empty input, so I change it's signature to

```
def foo(b: Option[Int]) = ???
```

Now `foo(a)` won't compile, because `a` isn't an `Option[Int]`, it's an `Int`. So you have to say `a = Some(3)` or `foo(Some(a))`, which seems redundant to me.

My question is, **why doesn't the language have an implicit conversion from `T` to `Some[T]`** (and vice versa)?

Is it a good idea to implement one yourself?

Comment: I don't really see, why you think it is redundant.

Comment: No, it is a bad idea to introduce such an implicit. It would make the language less strongly typed. implicit conversions are kind of power which requires responsibility (mostly for DSLs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could/should an implicit conversion from T to Option\[T\] be added/created in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746359/could-should-an-implicit-conversion-from-t-to-optiont-be-added-created-in-scal)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590756/scala-option-implicit-conversion-bad-practice-or-missing-feature