# Why is there an implicit conversion from Float/Double to BigDecimal, but not from String?

Tags: scala, floating-point, implicit, bigdecimal

Although the situation of conversion from `Double`s to `BigDecimal`s has improved a bit compared to Java

```
scala> new java.math.BigDecimal(0.2)
res0: java.math.BigDecimal = 0.20000000000000001110223024625156...

scala> BigDecimal(0.2)
res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.2
```

and things like

```
val numbers: List[BigDecimal] = List(1.2, 3.2, 0.7, 0.8, 1.1)
```

work really well, wouldn't it be reasonable to have an implicit conversion like

```
implicit def String2BigDecimal(s: String) = BigDecimal(s)
```

available by default which can convert Strings to BigDecimals like this?

```
val numbers: List[BigDecimal] = List("1.2", "3.2", "0.7", "0.8", "1.1")
```

Or am I missing something and Scala resolved all "problems" of Java with using the `BigDecimal` constructor with a floating point value instead of a `String`, and `BigDecimal(String)` is basically not needed anymore in Scala?

Comment: This has little to do with the Java language itself, why should it be tagged "Java"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was [thought of](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1813), but apparently [rolled back](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/18924) because it created ambiguous conversions. See [this thread on the scala-list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/17787).

The thread is old, but as far as I can see, string2Bigdecimal is [still not defined as an implicit](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/math/BigDecimal.scala).

If you still want to have a local `string2BigDecimal` implicit for your personal use:

- the rules for implicit scope can be found in the specification, §7.2,
- to resolve ambiguities in favor of your `string2BigDecimal`, you should define it using subclassing, see [this paper](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf) 
  (§6.5) for an example, and [this one](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/cunei/Thu,%202009-10-01,%2013:54/arrays.pdf) (§ *Avoiding Ambiguities*) for an explanation.

Comment: This is happened quite some time ago. I remember that there was something about being able to define a "precedence" of implicits with inheritance in the mean time. Wouldn't that work here? Or is this something completely different?

Answer (score 3):

Because a `BigDecimal` can *always* be created from a `Double` or a `Float`, but **not always** from a String. In general, it is a good idea that, where something has this "property" to use an *explicit implicit*. For example, this would be nice:

```
"1.23".toBigDecimal
```

Comment: Yes, that is certainly a valid concern, and the recommendations of [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404889/scala-implicit-usage-choices) certainly apply to having a toplevel `string2BigDecimal` implicit.